# Are you sure you want to proceed? on login after editing .bashrc

Tags: bash, mount, bashrc

Why am I being asked `Are you sure you want to proceed?` on login?

I just edited `.bashrc` and added below given line in it.

```
gnome-terminal -e "sudo -i mount -a"
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What's the purpose of that command? The equivalent of `mount -a` is already done during the regular boot procedure and in general there are better ways to run commands as super-user during system start-up.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why it would produce that specific message but you certainly don't want that command in your `.bashrc`. It is a very bad idea, for various reasons:

1. `.bashrc` is read each time you open a terminal. Do you really want a second terminal to launch each time you open one?
2. Why would you want to mount all drives each time you open a terminal or start a new shell? Any drives mounted by `mount -a` will already be mounted at startup anyway. If not, just run it manually, once. Why run it multiple times?
3. That will cause a terminal to appear asking you for your password each time a shell/terminal is started. Why would you want that?
4. This is a minor point, but there's absolutely no point in using `-i` when you're giving `sudo` a command to run. The `-i` is only useful when you want to start an interactive root shell.

In any case, this is clearly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). I suggest you post a new question explaining what you are trying to achieve and we can give you a better way of doing it.